# MethodNotAllowedException on PUT request Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, http, routes

I'm trying to do a PUT request on my form using Laravel, and it is returning a MethodNotAllowedException, the form is as follows:

`<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('negocio.update', $negocio->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

`{{ method_field('PUT') }}`

`</form>`

And my route is registered as:

`Route::put('/update/{id}', ['as' => 'negocio.update', 'uses' => 'client\NegocioController@update']);`

Using the `php artisan route:list` command gives me the following route:

`| PUT      | update/{id}            | negocio.update | App\Http\Controllers\client\NegocioController@update                   | web`

Can someone explain me, what am I doing wrong? I have already searched on different sites but no solution.

***UPDATE:**

I opened the browser inspector to see what kind of request was doing and it is trying to access another route using get method, which I do not have registered so that's why the error is displaying, but the thing is, I don't know why the form is submitting to another url.

Comment: What does the rendered content of {{ route('negocio.update', $negocio->id) }} turn out to be? is it the GET method you mentioned?

Comment: The render content is for example: `(base_path)/update/2`... but, I have just fixed the problem but I don't know why it wasn't working, the previous request that lead to the "PUT" form was a POST request, and I changed it to a GET one, and now it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `negocio` is a resource controller, and you have it in the web.php file like this: `Route::resource('negocio','NegocioController');`, try and do in like this:

```
    <form method="POST" action="{{route('negocio.update', $negocio->id)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}{{csrf_field()}}
    </form>
```

But dont use this(delete it or comment it out):

```
Route::put('/update/{id}', ['as' => 'negocio.update', 'uses' => 'client\NegocioController@update']);
```

**If it's not a resource controller**, then declare it in the route file like so:

```
Route::put('/update/{id}', 'NegocioController@update')->name('negocio.update');
```

If this dont do the trick, then try it with Post, and let the `{{method_field('Put')` do the trick.

```
Route::post('/update/{id}', 'NegocioController@update')->name('negocio.update');
```

Hope this helps. and if so, please tell us here.